# Aren't L-U decomposition and tridiagonal method the same?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I am asked to solve the following system of equations first with tridiagonal method and second with the L-U decomposition method:

$${ \begin{cases}{2x_1+x_2=3} \\ {-x_1+2x_2+x_3=2} \\ {-x_2+2x_3+x_4=2} \\ {-x_3+2x_4+x_5=2} \\ {-x_4+2x_5=1}\end{cases} }$$

But My question is . aren't them the same ? I mean in both method we write matrix of coefficient and decompose it to lower triangular matrix and upper triangular matrix. so what I suppose to do here?

Comment: No they're not the same. See this [link](https://www.uni-muenster.de/imperia/md/content/physik_tp/lectures/ws2016-2017/num_methods_i/appendix.pdf) for the tridiagonal algorithm.

Comment: @Chrystomath thanks. but I should to do this in this way: 

  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UKoReqs_MzK3xdXyg8SrTqh75uI5ksK7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It decomposed the matrix (like L-U method). I am confused why this is different from the method in your link?